# RESTful endpoints and database relationships

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am new in RESTful development. I'm developing a small application (with SpringBoot) that shows the list of states, regions and provinces. This is my databse diagram:
[image]

I'm having trouble creating endpoints for resources.
It is correct to create these endepoints:

```
/api/states      **//List of all countries** 
/api/states/{id} **//Show the single country**
/api/states/{id}/regions  **//Show all regions**
/api/states/{id}/regions/{id} **//Show the individual region**
/api/states/{id}/regions/{id}/provinces **//Show all provinces**
/api/states/{id}/regions/{id}/provinces/{id} **//Show the individual province**
```

I'm realizing that my endepoint is getting too long and I think this is not the right process.
Based on your experience which suggestion can you recommend?
Thank you

Comment: REST hasn't anything to do with your URI structure as clients adhering to the REST architecture will just use the URI but not interpret it. The URI relation name is probably more important than your URI structure. Any answers are thus highly opinionated. Next, a direct mapping of your DB model onto resources isn't the best choice in general as resources may contain plenty more links and stuff that might not be available in your model

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. My difficulty was just creating endepoints that respects the relationship of my database of the databaese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/api/states //List of all countries
/api/states/{id} //Show the single country
/api/states/{id}/regions //Show all regions
```

The endpoint above are good.

The problem exists in the rest of the nesting. With the assumption that the region and province ids are globally unique, they can be flatten in the same way (without including with states).

Below is the example:

```
/api/regions/{id} //Show the individual region
/api/regions/{id}/provinces //Show all provinces
/api/provinces/{id} //Show the individual province
/api/provinces/{id}/towns //Show all towns
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I suppose (after looking at the database schema) that all of your `states`, `regions` and `provinces` already have unique identifiers you could simply go ahead an trim the `/api/states` from all resources other than `states`. This combined with the fact of using query parameters to filter out `provinces`/`regions` for specific ids.

So would end up with the following endpoints

```
+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                   Endpoint                   |                       Description                       |
+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| `/api/state`                                 | Get a list of States                                    |
| `/api/state/<id>`                            | Get a specific State                                    |
| `/api/region`                                | Get a list of regions                                   |
| `/api/region?state_id=<id>`                  | Get a list of regions from a specific state             |
| `/api/region/<id>`                           | Get a specific region                                   |
| `/api/province`                              | Get a list of provinces                                 |
| `/api/province?state_id=<id>&region_id=<id>` | Get a list of provinces based on state_id and region_id |
| `/api/province/<id>`                         | Get a specific Province                                 |
+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now with theses routes/endpoints being layed out it is also kind of obvious on how to actually create those resources via the API. Either by using `POST` or `PUT` if the client of the API is aware of the resulting `<id>` of a resource.

Also please take into account what @roman-vottner said in his comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally with you up to a point:

/api/states - Yes, list all states
/api/states/{id} - Yes, show that one state
/api/states/{id}/regions - Yes, just regions in that state

But now I would go this route:

/api/regions/{id} - Show one region
/api/regions/{id}/provinces - Show all provinces in that region
/api/provinces/{id} - Show one province

You only need one {id} per request, I find.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can have a single Controller which handles all combination of queries.
For example you can have Controller MapController mapped to  url /api/MapController.
Inside this controller we can define a method where we can put our logic to handle different type of queries as shown in below example.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/MapController")
public class MapController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getdata",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void process(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputs) 
    throws Exception {
       if(inputs.get("country_id")){
          //fetch specific country_data
          if(inputs.get("state_id")&&(state_id in country_data){
               //fetch specific state_data
               if(inputs.get("region_id")&&(region_id in state_data){
                      //fetch specific region_data
                      if(inputs.get("province_id")&&(province_id in region_data){
                           //fetch specific province_data
                      }
                      else{
                          return region_data.name //specific region details
                      }

                }
                else{
                   return state_data.name  //specific state details
                }
           }
           else{
                return country_data.name //specific country details
           }
       }
       else{
          //Return All the countries
       }
       System.out.println(payload);

    }
```